# Cascading RegexSplitGenerator confused

Tags: cascading

I am looking the Cascading tutorial on its official website. It has the following input:

```
doc_id  text
doc01   A rain shadow is a dry area on the lee back side of a mountainous area.
doc02   This sinking, dry air produces a rain shadow, or area in the lee of a mountain with less rain and cloudcover.
doc03   A rain shadow is an area of dry land that lies on the leeward (or downwind) side of a mountain.
doc04   This is known as the rain shadow effect and is the primary cause of leeward deserts of mountain ranges, such as California's Death Valley.
doc05   Two Women. Secrets. A Broken Land. [DVD Australia]
```

It looks like the TSV format.

And in its WordCount program, it has the following code:

```
Fields token = new Fields("token");
Fields text = new Fields("text");
RegexSplitGenerator splitter = new RegexSplitGenerator(token, "[ \\[\\]\\(\\),.]");
```

So I am just confused what  "[ \[\]\(\),.]" means? Is it just grep the second part of the input file each line and named in as "token" Field?

Answer (score 1):

To understand what this regex mean, let's take a look into 2 things first

1. What is here that we are trying to achieve?
2. What does our data look like?

Answers to the above questions is

1. We are trying to solve word count problem.
2. The data has

   ```
   a. words
   b. commas ','
   c. dots '.'
   d. square open and closing brackets '[' and ']'
   e. round open and closing brackets '(' and ')'
   f. spaces
   ```

So let's again see look at the #1 question, i.e count words and before we do that we have to remove commas, dots, square brackets, round brackets and spaces.

Now, we are ready to look at the regex

```
Regex:[ \\[\\]\\(\\),.]
```

Let's expand

```
\\[   --> will remove all square open brackets
\\]   --> will remove all square close brackets
\\(   --> will remove all round open brackets
\\)   --> will remove all round close brackets 
,     --> will remove all commas
.     --> will remove all dot
space --> if you look closely at the regex, it actually has a space at the very beginning which removes all the spaces from the data.
```

After the regex execution, only words remains, which can be used for word count.

Answer (score 0):

The outer brackets `[]` define a character class.

The regex matches a single character which may may be a space, an open bracket, a close bracket, an open parenthesis, a close parenthesis, a comma, or a period.

The backslashes are involved in two levels of escaping:

1. Two backslashes produce a single backslash in the literal string.
2. A single backslash ensures that the next character is treated as literal, not regex character with special meaning.

BTW, I'm not sure if `\\(\\)` is necessary. I thought `()` should be sufficient inside a character class, but I might be wrong. When inside a character class, characters are treated as literals, though you still have to be careful about escaping brackets, so as to not end the regex early.

Comment: If I want to use a specific splitter such as "*", how can I change that part?

Comment: @user2597504, in regex, `*` is a special character meaning "zero or more". Use `\\*` or `[*]` to split by a literal asterisk.